# Drawing Balls in a Canvas - How to Replicate One Ball into Many Balls

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, jquery-animate

I want to simulate a box of random moving balls.
I have created a canvas with just 1 moving ball.
I want to replicate the ball into other balls so that they could start from a specific direction and move in random directions independently.
The code below is used to create the canvas of 1 moving ball.
Can you guys help me to replicate the balls and have them move in random directions?

I am using Javascript, HTML5 and PHP.*emphasized text*

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas { margin:0 20px 10px 200px; width:700; height:400; border:solid #CC0000; border-radius:15px;}
</style>
<canvas id="move"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('move');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var x = canvas.width / 2 + 100; //starting position
var y = canvas.height / 2 + 100;

var ball = canvas.getContext('2d');
ball.fillStyle = '#FF0000'; //color
var radius = 30;
var dx = 10;
var dy = 10;
var delta = 55; // range (from 0) of possible dx or dy change
var max = 215; // maximum dx or dy values
canvas.addEventListener("click", togglestart);

function togglestart() {
    if (interval == undefined) interval = window.setInterval(animate, 10000 / 60); // 60 FPS
    else {
        interval = clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(interval);
    }
}

var interval = window.setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);

function animate() {
    var d2x = (Math.random() * delta - delta / 2); //change dx and dy by random value
    var d2y = (Math.random() * delta - delta / 2);

    if (Math.abs(d2x + dx) > max) // start slowing down if going too fast
        d2x *= -1;

    if (Math.abs(d2y + dy) > max) d2y *= -1;

    dx += d2x;
    dy += d2y;

    if ((x + dx) < 0 || (x + dx) > canvas.width) // bounce off walls
        dx *= -1;

    if ((y + dy) < 0 || (y + dy) > canvas.height) dy *= -1;

    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    ball.beginPath(); //drawing ball
    ball.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ball.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // CLS clear the canvas
    ball.fill();
}

</script>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: Create an array `balls = [];` and then iterate the array drawing each ball. Clear the canvas before you draw the balls. If you are unsure how to use arrays you will need to a little more research to improve your coding skills.

Comment: @Doktor, what you suggested in coding format should look like this: var balls[]=10; for each balls[] As ball { ball.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); ball.beginPath(); ball.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,false); ball.fill(); }

Please if this isn't what you meant, kindly assist me here. Thank you.

Comment: @Eyo yes that's probably the JavaScript way of doing it. I was mixing things over in my head, sorry.